# How to Pass Custom Parameters to Event Handler

Tags: javascript, dojo, dom-events

Just getting started with Dojo.  I want to pass a couple of custom parameters to an event handler.  In jQuery, you can do it like this:

```
$('#button').click({
    customData: 'foo'
}, handlerFunction);
```

And `customData` can be accessed from `handlerFunction` like this:

```
function handlerFunction(event) {
    console.log(event.data.customData);
}
```

I'm migrating a bit of jQuery code over to Dojo.  How can I pass those parameters to the Dojo event handler?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, generaly, closures allow you to pass "hidden" parameters to a function:

```
function make_event_handler(customData){
    return function(evt){
        //customData can be used here
        //just like any other normal variable
        console.log(customData);
    }
}
```

So when connecting an event in dojo:

```
dojo.connect(node, 'onclick', make_event_handler(17));
```

Another possibility that I like a lot is using dojo.partial / dojo.hitch to create the closures for you.

```
function event_handler(customData, evt){
     ///
}

dojo.connect(node, 'onclick', dojo.partial(event_handler, 17))
```

---

Note that all of these these required your event handlers to be created with passing the extra parameter(s) in mind. I don't know if you can do a more direct translation of the JQuery code since that would require extra massaging of the evt variable and I don't think dojo does that.

Comment: Aha, `dojo.partial` is just what I'm looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Also:

```
this.connect(other, "onClick", function(e) { 
    /* other is accesible here still */ 
});
```

or :

```
this.connect(other, "onClick", dojo.hitch(this, "handler", other);
```

and its event handler:

```
this.handler = function(other, evt){...}
```